# Can read from, but cannot write to secure directory in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permission-denied

everyone. I'm trying to write a PHP script that reads and writes files from a secure directory. That is, a directory that users can't access. I put the "deny from all" in the .htaccess of said directory, and PHP scripts can read files from that directory without error. However, I cannot write files *to* that directory. I get a Permission Denied error when I try to use fopen with the "w" option.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: check the unix file permissions on the directory. does the webserver user have write access ?

Comment: If you're on a linux box, check the permissions for the file by `cd`ing to the directory that contains it and using `ls -al` to view owner and permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) function in php to check whether you have permission to write in to a directory. If not you can use [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to change the permission and write to it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I couldn't use chmod from the PHP script and change permissions ("Operation not permitted"), I had to chmod from the terminal and change permissions. Thanks for the suggestions.